# Regex for removing spaces and random trailing chars

Tags: regex

I am successfully validating an ID such as:

```
ZFA1G2H34J5K6L7P5
```

using this regex:

```
([a-h,A-H,j-n,J-N,p-z,P-Z,0-9]){17}$
```

This ID sometimes arrives corrupted (comes from a OCR process) and therefore the previous regex does not work. I need to support the most common way of corruption which is having a space within the ID:

```
ZFA1G2H34 J5K6L7P5
```

The regex should remove the space and compose  just the allowed 17 chars of the ID.

Please note I cannot use scripting (`.replace` for example) because the software where this regex is used does not support it.

As a bonus, sometimes the ID contains trailing chars which I would like to remove as well:

ZFA1G2H34 J5K6L7P5...ç

Comment: Remove all invalid characters using `[^a-h,A-H,j-n,J-N,p-z,P-Z,0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following regular expressions to validate the query:

```
^(?:(?![iIoO])[ ç0-9a-zA-Z]){17,}$
^([ ça-hA-Hj-nJ-Np-zP-Z0-9]){17,}$
```

And then, you can use the following regular expression to only match characters you like:

```
(?:(?![iIoO])[0-9a-zA-Z])
[a-hA-Hj-nJ-Np-zP-Z0-9]
```

*Don't use `,` in a set like `[A-Z,a-z]`, because commas are actually part of the set and not a separator between the character ranges.*

Comment: thanks, but I have to do everything in just one regex (software limitation).